# How to express an "A, then (B or C)" invocation order in Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I have three methods that are invoked on a mocked object. It is important that one of the methods is invoked before the other two, but I'm not concerned which order the final two are invoked in.

Can this logic be expressed with Mockito? As far as I can tell, the [`InOrder`](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/InOrder.html) class will force me to order all three invocations, as shown below:

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mock);
inOrder.verify(mock).crucialMethod();
inOrder.verify(mock).methodX();
inOrder.verify(mock).methodY(); // <-- I wouldn't care if this was invoked
                                //     before methodX()
```

I'd like to solve this so that my tests are less tightly coupled to the exact order the final two methods are invoked in.

*It's possible [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421014/mockito-how-do-you-verify-the-group-order-of-certain-groups-of-method-calls) is a duplicate, but I've struggled to understand exactly what the OP was seeking, nor whether the answer applies to me.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use two InOrder objects:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InOrder;
import org.mockito.exceptions.verification.VerificationInOrderFailure;

public class MyTest {

    public interface ToBeTested{
        public void crucialMethod();
        public void methodX();
        public void methodY();
    }

    @Test
    public void testXThenY(){
        // Given
        ToBeTested toBeTested = mock(ToBeTested.class);

        // When
        toBeTested.crucialMethod();
        toBeTested.methodX();
        toBeTested.methodY();

        // Then

        InOrder inOrderX = inOrder(toBeTested);
        inOrderX.verify(toBeTested).crucialMethod();
        inOrderX.verify(toBeTested).methodX();

        InOrder inOrderY = inOrder(toBeTested);
        inOrderY.verify(toBeTested).crucialMethod();
        inOrderY.verify(toBeTested).methodY();
    }

    @Test(expected=VerificationInOrderFailure.class)
    public void crucialTooLateForX(){
        // Given
        ToBeTested toBeTested = mock(ToBeTested.class);

        // When

        toBeTested.methodX();
        toBeTested.crucialMethod();
        toBeTested.methodY();

        // Then

        InOrder inOrderX = inOrder(toBeTested);
        inOrderX.verify(toBeTested).crucialMethod();
        inOrderX.verify(toBeTested).methodX();

        InOrder inOrderY = inOrder(toBeTested);
        inOrderY.verify(toBeTested).crucialMethod();
        inOrderY.verify(toBeTested).methodY();
    }

    @Test(expected=VerificationInOrderFailure.class)
    public void crucialTooLateForY(){
        // Given
        ToBeTested toBeTested = mock(ToBeTested.class);

        // When

        toBeTested.methodY();
        toBeTested.crucialMethod();
        toBeTested.methodX();

        // Then

        InOrder inOrderX = inOrder(toBeTested);
        inOrderX.verify(toBeTested).crucialMethod();
        inOrderX.verify(toBeTested).methodX();

        InOrder inOrderY = inOrder(toBeTested);
        inOrderY.verify(toBeTested).crucialMethod();
        inOrderY.verify(toBeTested).methodY();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I hadn't realise that the `InOrder` classes worked in that fashion.